# Azure AD conditional policy issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We have AAD conditional access policy which applies to specific apps, to all users in the directory and all type of client app in condition.

We can see it working as expected however for external users MFA comes only in case of when they access web application and MFA policy does not apply If they access the mobile application.
We have one app which is configured as web and mobile and desktop app, using both platforms in the same under app registration.

I have checked all possibilities but no luck, can you suggest?

Comment: Hi @sunny, please share the complete steps or screenshots you have configured in your CA policies.

Comment: I fixed this issue, it was related to v1 and v2 endpoints. Thanks for the support.